# unable to get entire html table content while web crawling through python in jupyter

Tags: python, web-crawler

from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time

```
class CrawledArticle():

    def __init__(self, heading, message):
        self.heading = heading
        self.message = message

class ArticleFetcher():

    def fetch(self):
        url = "https://www.agrarwetter.net/Agrarwetter-Aktuell/Stuttgart.Ist.html"
        articles = []
        time.sleep(1)
        r = requests.get(url)  
        doc = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        #tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

       # print(doc.select_one('.MITTEFORMULARSPALTE_WETTER').text.strip())
        for item in doc.select('.td_INHALT_MITTE'):
            #heading = item.select_one('.MITTEFORMULARSPALTE_WETTER').text.strip()
            heading = item.select_one('.SCHRIFT_FORMULARFELDBESCHRIFTUNG_MITTE_WETTER').text.strip()
            message = item.select_one('.td_INHALT_MITTE .SCHRIFT_FORMULAR_WERTE_MITTE:not(.pull-right)').text.strip()
            crawled = CrawledArticle(heading, message)
            articles.append(crawled)

        return articles

a = ArticleFetcher()
b = a.fetch()
for item in b:
    print(item.heading,'\n' ,item.message)
```

Comment: Please explain what you expected & what happened instead.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: i want to fetch Datum, luftdruck, sichweite etc... but my code is only printing Datum : 14.11.2019 Donnerstag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.agrarwetter.net/Agrarwetter-Aktuell/Stuttgart.Ist.html', headers=user_agent)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')


table = soup.select_one('.FARBE_FORMULAR_MITTE') #Select the table containing the weather data
headers = [i.text for i in table.select('.SCHRIFT_FORMULARFELDBESCHRIFTUNG_MITTE_WETTER')] #pull a list of the headers in the table
infos = [i.text for i in table.select('.SCHRIFT_FORMULAR_WERTE_MITTE')] #pull a list of the data associated to the headers

data = dict(zip(headers,infos)) #Create a dict with the headers and information

pprint(data)
```

the output is:

```
{'Datum': '14.11.2019Donnerstag',
 'Luftdruck': '1001,7 hPa',
 'Sichtweite': 'über 70km',
 'Taupunkt': '-2,1 °C',
 'Temperatur': '8,6 °C',
 'Uhrzeit': '15.00 Uhr',
 'Wetterzustand': '',
 'Windgeschwindigkeit': '10,8 km/h',
 'Windrichtung': '',
 'relative Feuchte': '47 %'}
```